# Is there a way to enable tcp/ip protocol through powershell script or sql script?

Tags: powershell, sql-server, vagrant

The context: I got a Vagrantfile to provision a VM, this VM have SQL-SERVER 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 installed. When I check on the SQL SERVER CONFIGURATION MANAGER I saw that in every SQL-SERVER instance have the TCP/IP protocol disable.

Is there a way to enable them via powershell script or sql script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft already provides guidance on this topic.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-2017
>
> Using SQL Server PowerShell
>
> To Enable a Server Network Protocol Using

1. Using administrator permissions open a command prompt.
2. Start Windows PowerShell from the taskbar, or click Start, then All Programs, then Accessories, then Windows PowerShell, then Windows PowerShell.
3. Import the sqlps module by entering Import-Module "sqlps"
4. Execute the following statements to enable both the TCP and named pipes protocols. Replace <computer_name> with the name of the computer that is running SQL Server. If you are configuring a named instance, replace MSSQLSERVER with the instance name.
   To disable protocols, set the IsEnabled properties to $false.

```
$smo = 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.'  
$wmi = new-object ($smo + 'Wmi.ManagedComputer').
```

List the object properties, including the instance names.

```
$Wmi
```

Enable the TCP protocol on the default instance.

```
$uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='<computer_name>']/ ServerInstance[@Name='MSSQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Tcp']"  
$Tcp = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri)  
$Tcp.IsEnabled = $true  
$Tcp.Alter()  
$Tcp
```

Enable the named pipes protocol for the default instance.

```
$uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='<computer_name>']/ ServerInstance[@Name='MSSQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Np']"  
$Np = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri)  
$Np.IsEnabled = $true  
$Np.Alter()  
$Np
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked quiet well.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked out how to iterate through multiple instances installed on the same machine, but [here's a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76622382/1411058) to enable TCP and Named Pipes for a named instance.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the TCP/IP protocol in SQL Server can be done right from
SQL Server Configuration Manager, after expanding
"SQL Server Network Configuration" followed by "Protocols for MSSQLSERVER".

Right-click on "TCP/IP" and choose "Enable", and afterward
right-click "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" and choose "Restart".

For a PowerShell script, see the Microsoft article
[Enable or Disable a Server Network Protocol](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Thank you, I'm insterested to do the task via scripting, I'll check out the article.